# Can I get Tomcat running as a service to dump heap?

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory, hudson, tomcat6

I am attempting to have Tomcat, which is currently running as a service on a Windows 2003 box, dump heap on an `OutOfMemoryError`.

(Tomcat is running Hudson, which is reporting a heap space problem at the tail end of my build.  Running the build manually produces no such error.  The Hudson guys need a heap dump to get started.)

As instructed elsewhere, I've told the Apache Service Monitor to configure the JVM it uses to run Tomcat to dump heap when an `OutOfMemoryError` is encountered by adding the following to the JVM options:
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
Then I run the build again.  Sure enough, it reports there was a heap error.  I scan the entire disk looking for the default `java_pid123.hprof` file (where obviously `123` is replaced by the PID of the JVM).  No `.hprof` files exist anywhere.

I am caught in a catch 22: I need the heap dump for the Hudson guys to fix their memory leak, but I can't get the heap dump if I run Hudson under Tomcat.

Is there some special way, when Tomcat is running as a Windows service, to get a heap dump from it on an OutOfMemoryError?

The other thing I've tried is to tell it, on the Startup and Shutdown tabs, to use the "Java" option instead of the "jvm" option.  I believe this should tell the Service Manager to attempt to start Tomcat with a Java executable command instead of launching the `jvm.dll` directly.  When I do this, the service won't start.

Surely someone else has had a similar problem?

Comment: I should mention that I have attached to Tomcat with jconsole and observed that the heap usage never climbs above 60MB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After finally putting this one to bed, I wanted to answer this for others who might have the same problem.

First, if you install Tomcat on Windows, do not use the `.exe` installer, even though it is promoted by Apache.  It will not let you run Tomcat as anything other than the system account, no matter what you do.  It appears that the system account does not have privileges to write `.hprof` files in the current directory, and no amount of Windows security tweaking appears to make this problem go away.

OK, so you've installed Tomcat from the `.zip` distribution.  Install it as a service using the `service.bat` script.  Make sure it is set to run as a specific user that you created specifically for this purpose.  Make sure as well that the folder you want Tomcat to write to in the event of a heap dump is writable by that user.

Edit the `service.bat` file to include the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and the `-XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\whatever` options in the correct place (where you can put JVM options).  That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried -XX:HeapDumpPath option?

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp

Answer (score 1):

I found the following link, which describes how to configure the tomcat service (includes setting the java parameters). Not sure if it applies to the version you are running.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Comment: Thank you; that is indeed helpful, but I should have mentioned I'm running Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1):

When java process running as window service you can generate the heapdump using below steps,

1. Run the command console as Administrator
2. version of JDK (for jmap command) and JRE (Java app run environment) should be same.
3. Get the PID no of running window process for that java application from task manager
4. Execute below command

> jmap -dump:file=d:\heapdump\myHeapDump.hprof -F #PID_No#

If got any exception with JDK/JRE 7 try the same with JDK/JRE 8
 Actually I faced some issue in jmap with JDK 7, but when i moved to JDK 8, I were able to successfully generate the heap dump using same command

Answer (score 0):

The `.hprof` files are dumped in the current directory. Exactly what that means for a windows service is anyone's guess, assuming it means anything.

I suggest posting a new question (on http://superuser.com) asking what "current directory" means for a windows service.

Comment: Current directory, perhaps, but no .hprof file is present on the machine at all.

Comment: So it's possible that windows services have no "current directory", and windows is dumping the file into the void. My suggestion about finding out more about windows services stands.

Comment: The service monitor claims the current directory is C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat\Tomcat 6.0.  I've written a servlet that outputs a file to the current directory, and the file shows up in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

[From 20 Tips for Using Tomcat in Production](http://www.digitalsanctum.com/2007/08/18/20-tips-for-using-tomcat-in-production/)

Add the following to your JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh (or catalina.bat for Windows): -`XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/j2ee/heapdumps`

Comment: The problem of course is that neither script is invoked by the service monitor.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed tomcat with .exe you can configure tomcat service to use account other than local system account and you can assign that user rights on directory "c:\whatever" where you are creating your dump file. one thing here to remember tomcat service don't run with account having administrative privileges. so create a simple user in windows(member of user group) and set tomcat services to user this account. and give that user rights on "c:\whatever" directory. This resolves the user directory rights issue but you have to configure tomcat for Memory dumps errors.